# как сделать rest запрос по дате . Java springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Каждые два секунд , я получаю данные с сайта заношу их в бд и мне нужно сделать rest запрос по Date. Я сделал rest запрос по всем данным . Но конкретно по Date у меня возникают трудности . Скажите почему мой вариант не работает и как сделал этот запрос . пример запроса по Date: http://localhost:8080/weather/1568477593000 когда ввожу его то выводятся пустые скобки
Вот класс

```
public class GreetingController {
@Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
private final CustomerRepository repository;
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
public GreetingController(CustomerRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Scheduled(cron = "*/20 * * * * *")
public void  get() {
    String API_KEY = "a1f6d8b723c126a1e135e62c135042c9";
    String Location = "London,UK";
    String urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + Location + "&appid=" + API_KEY ;
    String coord = "";

    // Connect to the URL using java native library
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.
        String cord = rootobj.get("coord").toString();
        String weather = rootobj.get("weather").toString();
        String base = rootobj.get("base").toString();
        String main = rootobj.get("main").toString();
        String wind = rootobj.get("wind").toString();
        String clouds = rootobj.get("clouds").toString();
        String dt = rootobj.get("dt").toString();
        String sys = rootobj.get("sys").toString();
        String time = rootobj.get("timezone").toString();
        String idd = rootobj.get("id").toString();
        String name = rootobj.get("name").toString();
        String code = rootobj.get("cod").toString();
        Date date = new Date();
        repository.save(new Customer(cord,weather,base,main,wind,clouds,dt,sys,time,idd,name,code,date));
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }

        // save a couple of customers  cord,weather, base,main,wind,clouds,dt,sys,idd,name,code
}

@RequestMapping("{date}")
public Iterable<Customer> getAllUsers(@PathVariable Long date) {
    return repository.findByDate(new Date(date));
}

@RequestMapping(path="/all")
public @ResponseBody
Iterable<Customer> getAllUsers1() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

и интерфейс

```
package hello;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByDate(Date date);
}
```

Comment: Я проверил Ваш код и, похоже, он рабочий. Вопрос лишь только в том, откуда вы берете long представление даты (в Вашем случае "1568477593000"), которое потом вставляете в запрос? Ведь каждые 20 секунд будет вставляться новый long. Или Вы смотрите его сначала в "getAllUsers1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) private Date date = new Date();
```